# Change "selection" in inactive sheet. VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I realise that it's best practice to avoid using any selections at all in your code, but this is more out of curiosity than anything else. If you select a cell and then change your sheet, the selection in the inactive sheet is remembered.

To demonstrate; if I do something like

```
Sub schrodingers_copy()
Range("a1").Copy
Worksheets(2).Paste
End Sub
```

Then I can paste cell A1 in the active sheet into whatever "selection" is currently "selected" in the **inactive sheet**

Is there a way to get or change this "selection"?

Comment: What value are you trying to change? Where the `.paste` is done on worksheet 2?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes.  I want to change the "selection" in an inactive sheet.  This short paste routine is just to demonstrate that that selection does in fact exist.

Comment: To change the seleciton wouldn't you just be then setting the range? ie `Worksheets(2).Range("A1").PasteSpecial`

Comment: You really shouldn't use `Selection`, but I get what you're asking. First, I'd set the selection to a range variable. Then, you can tweak that as necessary. That should be cleaner than messing around with `.Select`.  IIRC, if you use `.Select` with an INACTIVE sheet, VBA tends to throw an error until you activate that sheet.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821951.aspx):  "*Destination* - Optional -  ...If this argument is omitted, the current selection is used...."

Comment: @Some_Guy - The `Selection` is actually a property, not an object.  It can return pretty much anything that can be selected via the UI.  Since Excel's object model is fairly decent in separation of concerns (looking at you, Word), it's better to think of it as a UI wrapper that allows you to determine what the user "selected".  It generally isn't that useful for doing actual "work".

Answer (score 3):

### [Range.Cells Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx):

> Because the Item property is the default property for the Range
> object, you can specify the row and column index immediately after the
> Cells keyword. For more information, see the Item property and the
> examples for this topic.
>
> Using this property **without an object qualifier** returns a Range object
> that represents all the cells on the **active worksheet**.

*my emphasis*

---

You're not qualifying your range, that is why this is happening

```
Sub schrodingers_copy()
Range("a1").Copy
Worksheets(2).Paste
End Sub
```

`Range("a1")` refers to `_GLOBAL.Range("a1")` where `_GLOBAL` is referring to `Activesheet`.

Had you qualified the original `.Range` with a sheet, this wouldn't happen. It doesn't matter if you actually use `.Select` or not.

---

#### Examples

Run this while Sheet1 is active. Then run it again (Sheet2 will be active)

```
Sub BadKitty()
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Select
    MsgBox Selection.Parent.Name
    Sheet2.Activate
    Selection = "What sheet is this"
    MsgBox Selection.Parent.Name
End Sub
```

---

Select C3 on Sheet4, then turn to Sheet3 and select A1. Then watch what happens here

```
Sub DontOpenTheBox()
    Dim x As String
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheet2.Range("B2") = Selection.Address
    Selection = "what sheet is this? "
    Sheet4.Activate
    x = Selection.Parent.Name
    MsgBox x
    Sheet3.Range("B2") = Selection.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: I think I'm missing the point you're trying to get at here.  If sheet1 is active, badkitty()copies to whatever cell was the last selection made in sheet 2.  If sheet 2 is active at the beginning, it fails.

Answer (score 2):

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821951.aspx) documentation for `Worksheet.Paste` method states, regarding the optional `Destination` parameter:

> A Range object that specifies where the Clipboard contents should be pasted. **If this argument is omitted, the current selection is used**.

Since the *current selection* is on another worksheet, only the *address* part of it is relevant, per the *remarks* section on the same page:

> *If you don't specify the Destination argument, you must select the destination range before you use this method.*
>
> ***This method may modify the sheet selection***, depending on the contents of the Clipboard.

So your question entirely boils down to how `Worksheet.Paste` deals with its `Destination` parameter when it's omitted and the clipboard contains a `Range` object.

Now, as other answers stated, an unqualified `Range` call is implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet`, so your clipboard contains `ActiveSheet.Range("A1")` after copying:

> ```
> Range("a1").Copy
> ```

When you `Paste` though, you *are* qualifying the destination - implicitly; the destination *must* be on whichever worksheet `Worksheets(2)` is referring to, because that's what you're calling `.Paste` against **and you haven't provided a Destination parameter**.

Consider this:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1") = "test"
Sheet1.Range("A1").Copy

Sheet3.Paste 'destination is [Sheet3!A1]
Sheet3.Paste Sheet1.Range("A2") 'destination is [Sheet1!A2]
```

So when a `Destination` is provided, it doesn't matter what sheet you've qualified the `Paste` call with. You ask:

> *Is there a way to get or change this "selection"?*

Yes: Provide a value for the `Destination` parameter!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, would a method like this work:

```
Sub testSelection()
' This is to show how to work with .Selection, but not actually
' using .Select/.Selection.  We're going to take the value in
' Sheet1, SELECTION, and place that value in the selection of Sheet2, B2.

Dim theSelection As Range
Set theSelection = Selection
Debug.Print theSelection.Address

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2).Value = theSelection.Value

'Now, we want to move ONE CELL RIGHT of the Sheet1 selection
Set theSelection = theSelection.Offset(0, 1)
Debug.Print theSelection.Address

End Sub
```

Again, it's best practice to [avoid `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) whenever possible, so as soon as you can, I'd set that to a range.